# print() not working in django

Tags: python, django

i'm getting error while using print(), in the following code

```
programsListItems = programsList['items']
programsNextPage = programsList['nextPageURL']
print("check")
```

and in the browser i'm getting error like this

```
write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

and the log is as follows

```
 File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\WORK\AdminDashBoard\admin_dashboard\search\views.py", line 99, in institutedetails
    print("check")
  File "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\codecs.py", line 377, in write
    self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: I suspect you've redefined `print` somewhere. Look for `def print` or `print =` in your code.

Comment: use logging module as you are doing we development, it is good practice to use logging instead of print

Comment: @Barmar only one print used

Comment: Are you sure not getting that error when remove print ?

Comment: @RajaSimon  when i removed print() no error will occur

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3? That error usually happens when you pass a bytestring to a method expecting an unicode string.

Comment: using python 3 @yorodm , its not even printing print("check")

Comment: @mymail Would you be able to edit your code so it shows more or the view function? From the stacktrace I'm suspecting there's something other than the `print` going on.